# Django backend in Rest-framework resource for eCommerce

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to create an eCommerce store's entire backend in django (using Restful framework APIs), I am looking for resource available online especially on github.

Ofcourse I have done extensive research but I am unable to find anything that is recently updated and yet simple enough for me to understand, as I am not expert in django yet.

All I want is a resource from where I can see overall flow and model it by using their models, views, serializers and permissions as a reference

Answer (score 2):

You can refer here: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/ecommerce/
I recommend this resource for using: https://github.com/mirumee/saleor

Answer (score 1):

Consult the following list for possible options:

https://github.com/wsvincent/awesome-django#ecommerce

This resource might be helpful to you in the future as well.